# Appending data to .txt file

Tags: python, list, random, printing

I am fairly new to python. I want to create a program that can generate random numbers and write them to a file, but I am curious to as whether it is possible to write the output to a `.txt` file, but in individual lists. (*every time the program executes the script, it creates a new list*)

Here is my code so far:

```
def main():
    import random
    data = open("Random.txt", "w" )

    for i in range(int(input('How many random numbers?: '))):
        line = str(random.randint(1, 1000))
        data.write(line + '\n')
        print(line)


    data.close()
    print('data has been written')
    main()
```

Comment: change the mode from `w` to `a`

Comment: Done, but rather than it simply adding another number/set of numbers to the file I'd like there to be something separating the different entries

Comment: you can use a timestamp too

Answer (score 1):

ABout append or `a` -

> Opens a file for appending. The file pointer is at the end of the file
>   if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode. If the
>   file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing.

```
def main():
    import random
    data = open("Random.txt", "a" ) #open file in append mode
    data.write('New run\n') #separator in file
    for i in range(int(input('How many random numbers?: '))):
        line = str(random.randint(1, 1000))
        data.write(line + '\n')
        print(line)

    data.close()
    print('data has been written')
main()
```

Comment: Just remembered, you could have a `timestamp` as a separator

Answer (score 0):

If you read through the documentation for [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) you'll note:

> Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and
>   writing); note that 'w+' truncates the file. Append 'b' to the mode to
>   open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between
>   binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction,
>   adding the 'b' has no effect.

So use mode `a` if you want to "append to the open file.

**Example:**

```
f = open("random.txt", "a")
f.write(...)
```

**Update:** If you want to separate entries from subsequent program runs you'll have to append a line fo the file that your program *understand*. e.g: `f.write("!!!MARKER!!!\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same like `letsc` answer, but formatted to be more "pythonic"

Python 3 example, as was used print() in OP syntax.

```py
import random

def main():   
  with open("Random.txt", "a") as data: 
    print('New run', file=data)
    numbers_count = int(input('How many random numbers?: '))
    for i in range(numbers_count):
      line = str(random.randint(1, 1000))
      print(line, file=data)
      print(line)

  print('data has been written')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```